# Function .contains() not working in Groovy on expected way

Tags: java, groovy, contains

I am trying to check if number is member of list by using Groovy programming language.

I have this piece of code:

```
List<Long> list = [1, 2, 3]
Long number = 3

println(list.contains(number))​
```

Expected output is `true`, but the result I get is `false`.

Does anybody have an explanation?

Comment: Have you tried a primitive long?

Comment: I know how to handle this, but I am more interested why is this not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type parameters don't feature at runtime. Check this:

```
List<Long> list = [1, 2, 3]
list.each{println it.getClass()}
```

Which prints:

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
```

The true confusion is introduced by the bizarre behavior difference between `.equals` and `==` implementations:

```
Long.valueOf(3).equals(Integer.valueOf(3))
===> false
Long.valueOf(3) == Integer.valueOf(3)
===> true
```

`List.contains` seems to be using `.equals`, which checks the class of the parameter, thus explaining why forcing element types to `Long` resolves the problem.

So, in the midst of this uncertainty, I think the only sure thing is that Groovy's `==` execution performs the most intuitive and predictable comparison. So I'd change the check to:

```
boolean contains = list.grep{it == 3L} //sets value to true if matches at least 1
```

It helps when one doesn't have to be cognizant of data types linked to literals:

```
def ints = [1, 2, 3]
def longs = [1L, 2L, 3L]

boolean found1 = ints.grep{it == 3L}
boolean found2 = ints.grep{it == 3}
boolean found3 = longs.grep{it == 3L}
boolean found4 = longs.grep{it == 3}

println found1
println found2
println found3
println found4
```

Which works as anyone would want:

```
true
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the special literal values for longs: 1L instead of 1.

```
List<Long> list = [1L, 2L, 3L]
Long number = 3L
```

1 is an int. 1L is a long.

Comment: I get that, but for me is very strange that if I declare list of Long-s, that they won't be recognised as Long-s

Comment: I agree it's unexpected (I'm coming from a Java background too.)  Note that this will work as you expect: `list.any(number)`

Comment: This is how generics are implemented in the JVM. You can use GroovyConsole or a debugger to inspect the actual list. The type is `ArrayList`. The information of the element type is lost. You can even write `List<String> list = [1L, 2L, 3L]` and it wouldn't matter.